# Looking up values in html in background of iOS app

Tags: html, ios, swift, web-crawler

I'm new to iOS development and I'm trying to make an app that tracks my student loans. I would like to have the app simply display a balance found on the loan's website and build on that behavior. I've got my app to open up safari to the website but I'd like more of a web-crawling behavior so it's done in the background. This web-crawler needs to be able to login to the website and then find a field with the loan balance value..

I've looked up several ways on how to do this but I can't get any of them to work with my novice level of experience with swift. If anyone has a recommendation and a direction to go with this, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this question is quite broad, and answers will depend a lot on the structure of that site and its authentication mechanisms. In general, you could first use a tool like https://www.charlesproxy.com/ to look at the requests/responses involved when using the web page in a browser, and then try to use [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) to replicate those requests, retrieve data, and parse it. Here is a basic tutorial to get you started with URLSession: [link](https://learnappmaking.com/urlsession-swift-networking-how-to/)

Answer (score 0):

I've written an app to get my uni's schedules, payment records, and grades by bypassing the login and gain access to API used by the website.

The step you could take are probably very similar to mine

- **Find out how the website authenticate its users** (could be by cookie, session id's etc) You need to have some knowledge on web too. You can use the network tab on Chrome/Brave/Safari or any other browser to see what the website is doing when you click on 'login' for example. You could use Charles too, 30 days of trial should be enough.
- **After authentication succeed, track what API route the website use to get the datas to html.** See what information you need to access the API route. Postman would be very handy to see the JSON response by the API.
- **To parse the response,** you can use URLSession or networking library like Alamofire to get the job done.

If you want to see how I did it, here's the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/kevinyou77/Swordfish).